# A totally categorical structure with trivial geometry which is not interpretable in the trivial structure

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Among the theorems of early geometric model theory there is one by Lachlan stating that every totally categorical structure with a trivial pregeometry is intrepretable in a dense linear order.

That suggests in particular that there are totally categorical structures with a trivial pregeometry that are not interpretable in the trivial structure $(M,=)$. Could someone kindly give an example of such a structure?

Comment: @MostafaMirabi Please do not make trivial edits to old posts, especially in such mass numbers. These clutter up the main page. This has been discussed a few times on the meta, see e.g. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/599 .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK. sorry, I did not attention to these clutter.

Comment: Reposted with more details as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/231791 .

Answer (score 8):

One example is the theory of a unary functions satisfying $f^2(x) =x$.

As pointed out below by Eric, (with the explicit example of someone else) I was thinking only of 1-dimensional interpretations.

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow!

Comment: Could you tell a bit more precisely what structure you have in mind? For example, if for all $x$, $f(x)\neq x$, then this is interpetable in $(M,=)$ with the universe defined by $x \neq y$ and $f(x,y)=(y,x)$.

Comment: sorry, Neglected to say $f(x) \neq x$ and  `there exist infinitely many elements' to get a complete theory.

Comment: Sure, but as I have said, such a structure is interpretable in $(M,=)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, interpreted in (M,=) means there must be formula in only = that defines the function f.  An easier way to see the example might to write it as equivalence relation so that each class has size 2.  No formula of equality can define that equivalence relation.

Comment: @JohnBaldwin Your claim only holds for 1-dimensional interpretations. Dima Sustretov gave above an explicit 2-dimensional interpretation of your theory in $(M,=)$.

Answer (score 4):

An example of such a structure is given here: [ω-categorical, ω-stable structure with trivial geometry not definable in the pure set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231791/%CF%89-categorical-%CF%89-stable-structure-with-trivial-geometry-not-definable-in-the-pur?noredirect=1#comment573324_231791). Essentially, it is a non-split cover of the theory of the pure set. As in the paper of Hrushovski on Totally Categorical Structures.