# ω-categorical, ω-stable structure with trivial geometry not definable in the pure set

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Briefly, my question is the following.

*does every countable ω-categorical, ω-stable structure with 
disintegrated strongly minimal sets interpret in the countable pure set?*

By countable pure set I mean a structure with countable universe and equality relation only.

---

This is a repetition of this question [A totally categorical structure with trivial geometry which is not interpretable in the trivial structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68748/a-totally-categorical-structure-with-trivial-geometry-which-is-not-interpretable). However, I do not understand why the answer provided there is marked correct. (I agree with Dima Sustretov in the comments that the structure does interpret in the pure set).

The background to my question is the following.

It is shown in the paper of Cherlin, Harrington and Lachlan that
every ω-categorical, ω-stable structure is coordinatized by a collection of projective spaces, affine spaces and pure sets (which appear as strictly minimal sets in the expansion of the original structure by imaginaries). I'm interested in those structures in which only the pure sets appear. These were studied in the paper of Lachlan titled "Structures coordinatized by indiscernible sets". In this paper, it is shown that every such structure interpret in an arbitrary countable linear order,
and also, that such structures correspond precisely to reducts of totally categorical structures with trivial geometry (of the strongly minimal sets).

It is easy to see that every structure which interprets in the pure set is 
ω-categorical and ω-stable, and it follows from the paper of Lachlan that it is coordinatized by indiscernible sets (this even shown for structures which interpret in a dense linear order).

Therefore, we have the following implications:

*interprets in countable pure set → ω-categorical, ω-stable, with disintegrated strongly minimal sets → interprets in countable dense linear order.*

The second implication cannot be reversed (the dense linear order itself is not ω-stable). My question is whether the first implication can be reversed. In other words, this is the same question as asking about the existence of [A totally categorical structure with trivial geometry which is not interpretable in the trivial structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68748/a-totally-categorical-structure-with-trivial-geometry-which-is-not-interpretable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A totally categorical structure with trivial geometry which is not interpretable in the trivial structure](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68748/a-totally-categorical-structure-with-trivial-geometry-which-is-not-interpretable)

Comment: Posting a comment on John Baldwin's answer to the other question and tagging Dima Sustretov might draw their attention to the question again, so they can reevaluate or explain what's missing.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment there because I have no reputation :(. As soon as I earn it I will post a comment there.

Comment: Dear Szymon, I cannot remember now exactly why, but I accepted John Baldwin's anwer by mistake. I think one can construct the counterexample from my question as a non-split cover of the theory of $(M,=)$. This can be done for example using groupoids, as in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603413) article of Hrushovski

Comment: Dear Dima, thanks a lot for this. I will try to look into this article and exhibit an example; if I succeed, I will post it here.

Comment: @DimaSustretov It might be a good idea to unaccept the answer to avoid confusing other readers.

Comment: @SzymonToruńczyk to facilitate your task, I'll sketch my idea of the construction. Suppose you have a definable groupoid G, i.e. a pair of definable sets G_1 and G_0, and a collection of morphisms (source, tagret, composition etc), such that G_1(M) and G_0(M) together with these morphisms constitute a groupoid for any model M. Hrushovski defines the notion of equivalence of groupoids; a groupoid is called split if it is equivalent to a groupoid with trivial isomorphism groups of objects.

Comment: @SzymonToruńczyk One can associate an extra sort to a groupoid, and provided the groupoid is connected, this sort is interpretable in the base theory iff the groupoid is split (one can draw parallells with the notion of elimination of imaginaries here, the extra sort is like an imaginary sort). I believe one can find an example of an omega categorical omega-stable theory (perhaps even $(M,=)^{eq}$ will do) and a definable non-split groupoid in it, such that this theory with the generalized imaginary sort added has trivial geometry

Comment: @SzymonToruńczyk I can also recommend (shameless self-promotion!) to have a look at my [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2273) where the notion of a generilized imaginary sort is defined using the language of groupoid torsors, this definition might look slightly more natural to you than Hrushovski's

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "interpretable", do you mean with or without parameters? (the question seems interesting both ways)

Comment: @Alex both variants are equivalent. Since the structure (N, =) is ultrahomogeneous, if a structure A interprets in (N, =) with parameters a, b,..., k,  then it also interprets without parameters - one needs to include additional variables a, b,..., k,  make sure they have the right atomic type,  and quotient by the equivalence relation which says that the choice of the values for those variables is irrelevant.

Comment: @SzymonToruńczyk I don't understand what you mean by "the equivalence relation which says that the choice of the values for those variables is irrelevant". Any two realizations $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ of the same atomic type are conjugate by an automorphism of $N$, but not by a canonical one, so it's not clear how to identify a point of $\varphi(N,\overline{a})$ with a point of $\varphi(N,\overline{b})$. Maybe I've misunderstood you...

Comment: @AlexKruckman You're right, my vague idea was incorrect. Here's another attempt, which should work for $(\mathbb N,=)$. The idea is to represent parameters $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb N$ (wlog, pairwise distinct) by distinct atomic types in some $\mathbb N^k$. More precisely, let $k$ be large enough, so that $\mathbb N^k$ contains at least $n$ pairwise-distinct atomic types $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Now, we modify a $d$-dimensional interpretation using parameters $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ to a $k\cdot d$-dimensional one, defining an isomorphic structure. Single variables in the formulas defining the interpretation are replaced by $k$-tuples of variables, and an equality $x=a_i$ is replaced by the formula $\alpha_i(x)$. I don't know if this argument can be generalized to structures which interpret in an arbitrary ultrahomogeneous structure, and I'm no longer sure that it is true in general.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works. Thanks! Small correction: you need to pick $k$ large enough so that $\mathbb{N}^k$ contains $n+1$ atomic types (since you want to use an equivalence relation to collapse $n$ of the types into definable elements, while leaving the realizations of the last type as an infinite set). For example, you can get one definable element as a quotient of $\mathbb{N}^2$ (by collapsing the type $x = y$) but to get two definable elements, you need to go to $\mathbb{N}^3$.

Comment: You're right, you need one extra atomic type for the infinite set.

Comment: If we take an infinite graph of finite valency d, I believe is $\omega$-stable, $\omega$-categorical and its geometry is trivial. Doesit interpretable in the pure set? How? (btw, I also answered by mistake the question, does anyone know how to take it down?)

Comment: Any $\omega$-categorical graph $G$ in which every vertex has finite degree is a disjoint union of countably many graphs of bounded size: (1) the degree is bounded by some number $d$ for all vertices (by Ryll-Nardzewski theorem there are only finitely many orbits of vertices) and (2) for every pair of vertices $v,w$, the distance between $v$ and $w$ is either $\infty$ or it is bounded by a finite constant $r$ (again, there are only finitely many orbits of pairs of vertices), and therefore, every connected component has at most $d^r$ elements. It follows that $G$ interprets in the pure set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my question was given to me by Ehud Hrushovski, and is as follows
(the following formulation is my own).

Let $D$ be the pure set.
For each pair $\{a,b\}$ of distinct elements of $D$ let $C_{\{a,b\}}$ be a directed square, i.e., a directed cycle of length four, and let $f_{\{a,b\}}$ map the two elements of one of the diagonals of $C_{\{a,b\}}$ to $a$ and the remaining two elements to $b$.
Let $C$ be the disjoint union, over all pairs $\{a,b\}$, of the cycles $C_{\{a,b\}}$; $C$ is equipped with the directed edge relation $E$.
Let $f:C\to D$ be the disjoint union of all the maps $f_{\{a,b\}}$.

Now, the two-sorted structure $M=(D,C,E,f)$ is $\omega$-categorical, $\omega$-stable, has disintegrated strongly minimal sets, but does not interpret in the pure set. However, $M$ does interpret in $(\mathbb Q,\le)$ (this also proves $\omega$-categoricity of $M$). It is also a finite cover of a structure which interprets in the pure set, and a special case of a construction studied in Section 4 of the paper 'Totally categorical structures' by Hrushovski.

Comment: The $D$ at the beginning of the answer became $P$ toward the end.

Comment: This looks interesting, but can you enlighten us how to prove all the claims?

Comment: @AndreasBlass corrected – thanks.

Comment: I would also like to know how to show that this structure does not interpret in the pure set.

Comment: Could you tick your answer accepted so that the question is no longer bumped by the system?

Comment: @Ycor – done, thanks

Comment: Like Emil and Alex, I would also be interested in a seeing a proof of this.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I have posted a second answer containing proofs of the relevant claims.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg I have posted a second answer containing proofs of the relevant claims. (Apparently you cannot @ multiple people in a single comment.) Also, I have already shown this to Alex Kruckman via email.

Answer (score 5):

This is a follow-up to Szymon Toruńczyk's answer in which I will prove the claims in it.

**Proposition.**
$\mathrm{Th}(M)$ is totally categorical with trivial geometry.

*Proof.* First, note that $M = \mathrm{acl}(D)$. This implies that $D$ is stably embedded in $M$. Furthermore, we have that every permutation of $D$ extends (non-uniquely) to an automorphism of $M$. This implies that the induced structure on $D$ is that of an infinite pure set, so, in particular, $D$ is strongly minimal.

For any $N \equiv M$, we will also have that $N = \mathrm{acl}(D^N)$, so we get a unique model of each infinite cardinality. $\square$

**Proposition.**  $\mathrm{Th}(M)$ is not interpretable in the theory of an infinite pure set.

*Proof.* Let $N$ be a model of $\mathrm{Th}(M)$, and let $X$ be an infinite pure set. Suppose that $N$ is interpretable in $X$. So in particular, we have imaginary sorts $D'$ and $C'$ as well as a definable binary relation $E' \subseteq C'\times C'$ and a definable function $f':C' \to D'$ such that $(D',C',E',f')$ is isomorphic to $N$.

Since $\mathrm{Th}(X)$ is uncountably categorical, there is a strongly minimal set $S\subseteq D'$. Furthermore, there must be a definable finite-to-finite correspondence between $X$ and $S$. Since $X$ is a pure set, this must actually be a bijection on some cofinite set.

Let $Y\succ X$ be an elementary extension such that $|Y \setminus X| = 2$. Let the two new elements be $a_0$ and $a_1$. Let $S^Y$ and $C'^Y$ be the corresponding sets in the elementary extension, and let $b_0$ and $b_1$ be the new elements of $S^Y$ corresponding to $a_0$ and $a_1$, respectively. Finally let $c_0,$ $c_1,$ $c_2,$ and $c_3$ be elements of $C'^Y$ satisfying that $f'(c_0) =f'(c_2)=b_0$, $f'(c_1)=f'(c_3)=b_1$, and $c_0E'c_1E'c_2E'c_3E'c_0$.

Let $\sigma$ be the automorphism of $Y$ that fixes $X$ and has $\sigma a_0=a_1$ and $\sigma a_1 =a_0$. We necessarily have that $\sigma b_0 = b_1$ and $\sigma b_1 = b_0$.

There are only two possibilities for the value of $\sigma c_0$. Either $\sigma c_0 = c_1$ or $\sigma c_0 = c_3$. In both cases $\sigma^2 c_0 = c_2$, but $\sigma^2$ is the identity automorphism, so this is absurd.

Therefore no such interpretation can exist. $\square$

Comment: Cool. If I recall correctly, there is a theorem that if $M$ and $N$ are $\omega$-categorical structures then $M$ interprets $N$ iff there is a surjective morphism $\mathrm{Aut}(M) \to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$. I think your argument basically rules out such a morphism directly.

Comment: Now of course I want to know if this thing is trace definable in the trivial structure. I think that it should be, the main thing would be to figure out what the definable sets in this structure actually are.

Comment: Let $f_1 =f$ ($f$ as before) and $f_2$ be the function $C\to D$ where $f_2(a)=b$ if there is $c$ such that $aEc$ and $f_1(c)=b$.  For all $(i,j) \in \{1,2\}^2$ let $R_{ij}$ be the binary relation on $C$ where $R_{ij}(a,a')$ iff $f_i(a) = f_j(a')$.  So $(C,R_{ij})$ is bi-interpretable with $M$. I'm pretty sure that $(C,R_{ij})$ is homogeneous.

Comment: Assuming that claim, it's not hard to show that $(C,R_{ij})$ is trace definable in the trivial structure. But I don't see how to generalize this to the general Hrushovski construction that $M$ is a special case.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg Where is the general construction defined?

Comment: Definition 4.1 here https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-313-01/S0002-9947-1989-0943605-1/S0002-9947-1989-0943605-1.pdf